# @webmethod - does not expose the method as webservice (JAX-WS)

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a stateless session bean which is exposed as webservice. There are two methods and both have @webmethod annotation. But, only one of the method is exposed as webservice. Could anyone point out reason for this behaviour, please find the code below:

```
@WebService(portName = "interfaceSoapHTTPPort", serviceName = "interfaceService", targetNamespace = "http://com.demo.service/interfaceservice", endpointInterface = "com.demo.service.interfacePortType")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
@Stateless(mappedName = "InterfaceBean")

public class InterfaceBean {
    @PostConstruct
    @PostActivate
    public void initializeBean() {

    }

    @WebMethod
    public void processPathEvent(XngEvent pathXngEvent) throws WSException {

    }   

    @WebMethod
    public void portAssignmentUpdate(WSHeader wsHeader,
            PortAssignmentUpdateRequest portAssignmentUpdateRequest,
            Holder<WSResponseHeader> wsResponseHeader,
            Holder<PortAssignmentUpdateResponse> portAssignmentUpdateResponse)
            throws WSException {

    }
}
```

Only portAssignmentUpdate method is exposed as webservice, but not the processPathEvent method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

We have set "endpointInterface" property in @webservice annotation. I had forgotten to added the processPathEvent() method to this interface. Hence, the method was not exposed even when @webmethod annotation is added.